# RxJavaPlugins not working?

Tags: rx-java2

For instrumentation testing purposes I want to know when an observable is subscribed to and when it completes so that when all the worker threads are done, automated ui actions and assertions can be made.

Given the following code with RxJava2:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setOnSingleSubscribe((observable, observer) -> {
            observable.doFinally(() -> Timber.d("single finish"))
                    .doOnSubscribe(__ -> Timber.d("single subscribe2"))
                    .doOnSuccess(__ -> Timber.d("single success"))
                    .doOnEvent((__, ___) -> Timber.d("single event"))
                    .doOnError(__ -> Timber.e("single error"));
            Timber.d("single subscription");
            return observer;
        });
```

It only logs `single subscription` but never any of the other messages.

How is it supposed to work?

The code I used in RxJava1 was:

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnSingleStart { _, onSubscribe ->
      Timber.d("single subscription")
      return onSubscribe
}

RxJavaHooks.setOnSingleReturn { subscription ->
      Timber.d("single finish")
      return subscription
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is someone subscribing to the Observable or is anyone posting events to the Observable in question? Those side effect functions are called when something happens in the Observable stream.

Comment: Yes, there are events happening. The goal is to know when all the worker threads are done for instrumentation testing purposes.

Comment: This doesn't work because the callback expects you to manipulate the observer given the upstream observable and the downstream observer. Calling methods on the Single and then throwing away the result has no effect anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
        RxJavaPlugins.setOnSingleSubscribe((observable, observer) -> new SingleObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Timber.d("single subscription");
                observer.onSubscribe(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o) {
                Timber.d("single success");
                observer.onSuccess(o);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Timber.d("single error");
                observer.onError(e);
            }
        });
```